# Python and Selenium: Unable to locate a specific (href) element to click on

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape all of the data on [this](https://drugdesign.riken.jp/hERGdb/index.php) site.

This part of my script will click the 'search' button necessary to produce the rows of data that I want to scrape:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys
import re
import requests

#options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
base_url = 'https://drugdesign.riken.jp/hERGdb/'
driver.get(base_url)

#click the button that says search
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=Structure_Search]').click()
```

Then I need to click on each LOT_ID, which would bring me to a page like [this](https://drugdesign.riken.jp/hERGdb/compound.php?HGID=HG-0260086), which I can scrape with this code:

```
base_url = 'https://drugdesign.riken.jp/hERGdb/compound.php?HGID=HG-0260086'
driver.get(base_url)

## compound information table
hgid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/th[contains(.,"HGID")]/following::td[1]')
drug_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/th[contains(.,"Drug_name")]/following::td[1]')
MW = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/th[contains(.,"MW")]/following::td[1]')
Formula = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/th[contains(.,"Formula")]/following::td[1]')


## ID relation table
id_table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody')
for x in id_table:
       print(x.text)


## in vitro assay information table
assay_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/table[3]/tbody')
for x in assay_data:
       print(x.text)
```

I cannot understand how to loop through ALL of the LOT_IDs on the site (e.g. there are only 10 displayed per page, and there seems to be >300,000 results but only 1,000 displayed). So the ultimate question is how do I loop through ALL >300,000 LOT_IDs that they say are the results for my search, so I can run the second part of my code (above) on it (which runs on each individual page).

I have been looking through SO, I've tried something like:

```
#table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('//*[@id="foo-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a')
#print(table)
```

and similar using XPaths etc, but I get errors like:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
```

So if someone could fill in the middle part of my code (I think it should only be one or two lines max?) that would show me how to loop through the >300,000 LOT_IDs and click on them, to bring me to the page that I then scrape, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is it this page you are scraping? https://drugdesign.riken.jp/hERGdb/result.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all links using [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) and [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup). Code below print all 1000 links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://drugdesign.riken.jp/hERGdb"    
data = [
  ('smiles_S', ''),
  ('jme_S', ''),
  ('tab_selected', 'tab_S'),
  ('query_type', 'Substructure'),
  ('Target[]', 'hERG'),
  ('Target[]', 'Cav1.2'),
  ('Target[]', 'Nav1.5'),
  ('Target[]', 'Kv1.5'),
  ('Value_type[]', 'IC50'),
  ('Value_type[]', 'inhibition'),
  ('Value_type[]', 'other'),
  ('Assay_type[]', 'binding'),
  ('Assay_type[]', 'patch clamp'),
  ('Assay_type[]', 'other'),
  ('Data_source[]', 'ChEMBL'),
  ('Data_source[]', 'PubChem_CID'),
  ('Data_source[]', 'hERG Central(PubChem_SID)'),
  ('low_MW', ''),
  ('high_MW', ''),
  ('Assay_name', ''),
  ('Structure_Search', 'Search'),
]

response = requests.post(f'{base_url}/result.php', data=data)
lots = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser").select("a[href^='./compound.php?HGID=']")
for lot in lots:
    url = str(lot['href']).replace("./", "")
    print(f"{base_url}/{url}")
```

Comment: Nice answer with requests and BeautifulSoup. If you could explain to this to OP how you achieve this that would be great.I mean Network tab and so on.

Comment: @KunduK thank you for the appreciation for my effort, I'll try to explain if have time

Answer (score 0):

Here is selenium code to get all 1000 links.Use while loop and iterate each page get the link until Next button is disabled.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
base_url = 'https://drugdesign.riken.jp/hERGdb/'
driver.get(base_url)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='Structure_Search']"))).click()
targeturl=[]
while True:
    elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#foo-table_filter ~ #foo-table a")))
    for ele in elements:
        targeturl.append(ele.get_attribute('href').replace('./', ''))

    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.paginate_button.next.disabled"))>0:
        break
    nextbutton=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.paginate_button.next")
    nextbutton.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    nextbutton.click()

print(len(targeturl))
print(targeturl)
```